# PayPal .net API

Tags: paypal, sdk

just a general question Without getting into much details, does PayPal SDK have the functionality to access payments data from .net (C# desktop application).
i need to retreive customer details, date, reference and amount to be then able to post into another program ?

I have been doing some research on PayPal developer site, but couldnt find anything in relation to my query,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The [.net rest SDK](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-dotnet) provides access to the APIs at developer.paypal.com.